# Why is the top-bar still using the old style on stackexchange.com?

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, stackexchange.com

Why is the main stackexchange.com site still using the old style top-bar? It seems odd for that particular page not to match everything else at this point.

BAD:
[image: stackexchange.com]

GOOD:
[image: meta.stackexchange.com]

Comment: The functionality is different, for one thing.

Comment: I sort of like the one on top.

Comment: I never realized there's a "Main stackexchange" website.